# How Can we Associate both public IP and Elastic IP for an same Amazon EC2 ubuntu instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

We need to run two different applications on same instance on same port 80.
So I need suggestion to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use your DNS provider to map two host records to the same elastic IP and configure your virtual hosts in Apache to route the traffic based on host name.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a second [Elastic Network Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html) to your EC2 server. This will give you the capability of having a second public IP address (or Elastic IP) associated with your server. Then configure one application to bind to port 80 on the first ENI, and configure the second application to bind to port 80 on the second ENI.